# Using setprecision in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to use setprecision in c++. Here is what I am doing-

I have an output file, where I am writing the results-

My first call to function prints the interest_rate correctly.
Say, I call the function with `interest_rate=0.035`, so I get the following output  -

```
Annual Interest Rate: 0.035
```

But next time if I call with the function with same `interest_rate i.e. 0.035`, I get the following output-

```
Annual Interest Rate: 0.04
```

I want the same output in both the cases, why is this happening?

Edit:-
here is the code-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
```

Here is the input file:-
**input.txt**

```
3
1000.00
0.035
120.00
5000.00
0.04
165.00
200000.00
0.055
2250.00
```

Here is the output file I get:

```
Annual Interest Rate: 0.035
1         1000.00   
2         1000.00   
3         1000.00   
4         1000.00   
Annual Interest Rate: 0.04
1         5000.00   
2         5000.00   
3         5000.00   
4         5000.00   
Annual Interest Rate: 0.06
1         200000.00 
2         200000.00 
3         200000.00 
4         200000.00
```

Note how the 0.055 in the input file gets printed as 0.06 in the output file

Comment: Could you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: Your code does not match your problem. Can you show the code where "_the input is `0.035` but it outputs: `Annual Interest Rate: 0.035` then `0.04`_"?

Comment: You are both wrong, the code is sufficient and @Dieter's answer explains what is happening. Clarity could be improved on the second part but the info is there

Comment: @FirstStep I have added my code alongwith the input and output file

Answer (score 4):

Some stream manipulators/flags apply only once (e.g.: `setw`) and other remain valid until they are changed (e.g.: `fixed` and `setprecision`).

I assume, in the first call of the function you are using the default format (not `fixed` and not `scientific`) and default precision (6) of the stream.

In the second call of the function (I assume you do not change it meanwhile in another function) you have the format `fixed` and a precision of two.

Comment: @Joker this is the right answer. `setprecision(2)` is still in effect

Comment: @Dieter  Thanks for the answer, I tried changing the precision to default precision but then it outputs 0.035000 instead of 0.035. It sets back the precision to `6` as you said, but I want to display `0.035`.

Comment: That's because you've also set it as `fixed`. You can remove that with `outfile.unsetf(ios_base::fixed);`

Comment: @sokkyoku If I don't set it to fixed it displayed the result in scientific notation as follows-`2e+02 `

Comment: @sokkyoku Yes it worked. Thanks a lot